# Does TypeScript's tsc create a cache of previously transpiled files?

Tags: typescript, tsc

I created a definition file for greeter.ts, and then a number of other *.ts files.  When I ran `tsc --project ./tsconfig.tsc.json --declaration` it generated *.d.ts files for all of the other *.ts files, except for greeter.d.ts, which I'd manually created.  It refused to overwrite it.  So, I deleted greeter.d.ts and ran tsc again.  It outputs the same error `error TS5055: Cannot write file '~/project/greeter.d.ts' because it would overwrite input file.`, even though the file no longer exists.

So, why is tsc able to overwrite files it previously generated, but not the one I created?  Even more, it still thinks the manually created *.d.ts file exists after I deleted it.  Logically, there is a cache somewhere, but I haven't found information about it.

Is there a cache of previously transpiled files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it creates a cache.  I found how it "knows" that I manually created a definition file.  In my greeter.ts, I referenced it like so:

```
/// <reference path="greeter.d.ts" />
export class Greeter {

  public greeting: string;
  constructor() {
      console.log('Greeter()');
  }

  public activate() {
    this.greeting = 'hello worldz';
  }
}
```

Removing the reference cleared the error and tsc was able to create the file.